# Regular expression difference + and *

Tags: python, regex

This may be a dump question. But I have to ask to clarify  it.

I have a text

```
string = ''' t Network Questions
Is there         something like a (readied) charge in 5e?
 Can you use a
  Bonus Action on a       turn'''
```

The text is scattered purposefully. i came across this doubt accidentally.

```
print re.sub(r'\s+',' ',string)

 t Network Questions Is there something like a (readied) charge in 5e? Can you use a Bonus Action on     a turn
```

Have a look at the next statement.

```
 print re.sub(r'\s*',' ',string)

 t N e t w o r k Q u e s t i o n s I s t h e r e s o m e t h i n g l i k e a ( r e a d i e d ) c h a r g e i n 5 e ? C a n y o u u s e a B o n u s A c t i o n o n a t u r n
```

The only difference is * and +. So, what exactly it is meant by 0 or more occurrence and 1 0r more occurrence. Can anyone explain why its space between words when we are using *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How does `+` matches the string**

```
Is there         something like
  |
 \s #one space

Is there         something like
        |
       \s+ #one or more space 

Is there         something like
         |
        \s+ #one or more space

# And so on untile

Is there         something like
                |
               \s+
```

**How does ** matches the string**

```
Is there         something like
|
\s* #matches here. Because there is zero occurence of space (Before the character I)

Is there         something like
 |
 \s* # matches here as well and so on in all the characters

     #  Here it doesnt match any character, Rather it matches the postion between I and s as there is zero occurence of \s
```

Comment: This is the best explanation any one can give. Its good answer so nicely explained.

Answer (score 1):

```
`*` matches an empty string as well.
```

So between `Ne` there is one empty string.So it will be replace by space.

Comment: @ This a new information for me. Very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But how can we say that * matches only space occurrences It finds space between words which are actually not there.

Comment: @user3116355 it finds `an empty string of spaces`.

Answer (score 0):

`*` is zero or more Occurance , zero means empty

`+` is one or more Ocuurance, it matches at least one

Comment: But i am trying to match all spaces. But how can we say that * matches only space occurences It finds space between words which are actually not there.